# Possessive of dependency?

Tags: grammar

How does one write the possessive of dependencies?  So, in this example sentence fragment, each dependency owns a 'scheduled date'.

Would it be...

```
...before all dependencies scheduled date...
...before all dependency's scheduled date...
...before all dependencys' scheduled date...
```

Comment: If each dependency has a date, then it should be *dates*, plural. In any case, reword from scratch. What you have right now is no good, every which way you spell it.

Comment: The answer is below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the word already ends in an 's', you add just one apostrophe. This is both for singular words ending in 's', as well as plurals.

Example:

> The dependencies' scheduled dates...

Note how, since each dependency each has its own date, 'date' should also be plural.

Source and further reading:

https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/forming-possessive/